Claims Identity Not Authenticated After SignInAsync
I'm using Cookies Authentication, but after User Validate there is validated true.
screenshot.
But after Login, there is shown User Identity not Authenticated screenshot.
Here I mention Code snippet in .net Core:
 [HttpPost]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl = null)
  {
      ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;

      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {

          User user = validateUser(model.Email, model.Password);
          if (user != null)
          {
              // Valid user credentials


              // Sanitize user data before storing in cookie
              model.Email = Uri.EscapeDataString(model.Email);

              // Create authentication claims
              var claims = new List<Claim>
              {
              new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
              new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, user.UsEmail),
              // Add additional claims as needed
              };


              var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme));

              var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
              {
                  AllowRefresh = true,
                  IsPersistent = model.RememberMe, // Set persistence based on checkbox
              };

              try
              {
                  await _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                      claimsPrincipal,
                      authProperties);

                  var isAuth = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {
                  // Log error and handle accordingly
              }

              if (user.Role == "User")
              {
                  return LocalRedirect(returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/Home"));
              }
              else
              {
                  return LocalRedirect(returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/Admin"));
              }
          }
          else
          {
              ViewData["message"] = "Invalid login credentials.";
              return View();
          }
      }

      // If data is invalid (including potential SQL comment characters)
      ViewData["message"] = "Invalid Provided Data.";
      return View();
  }


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = "YourAuthCookieName";

        options.LoginPath = "/Auth/Login";
        options.LogoutPath = "/Auth/Logout";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/Error";

        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30); // Set cookie expiration for "Remember Me"
        options.SlidingExpiration = true; // Refresh cookie on activity
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true; // Mitigate XSS risks
      //options.Cookie.Secure = true;   // Enforce HTTPS-only cookies (if applicable)
    });


// Add IHttpContextAccessor
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddSession();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

I want to fetch Claims Values in Controller, but when I Call User in Controller there is null value.

I tested with your codes, it works well on my side,  you could check below image. I suggest you could try my works sample and check the browser has enabled the cookie , then check user.UsEmail and user.Id.ToString() is null or not.
Test result:
Inside home controller:

My test demo:
public class AuthController : Controller
{
    public IHttpContextAccessor  contextAccessor;
    public AuthController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor ) {
        contextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }


    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(  string returnUrl = null)
    {
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
 
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,"test" ),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email,"xxxxx@xxx.com"),
        // Add additional claims as needed
        };


        var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme));

        var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
        {
            AllowRefresh = true,
            IsPersistent = true, // Set persistence based on checkbox
        };

        try
        {
            await contextAccessor.HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                claimsPrincipal,
                authProperties);

            var isAuth = contextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log error and handle accordingly
        }
 
        // If data is invalid (including potential SQL comment characters)
        ViewData["message"] = "Invalid Provided Data.";
        return View();
    }

}

Program.cs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.Name = "test";

        options.LoginPath = "/Auth/Login";
        options.LogoutPath = "/Auth/Logout";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Home/Error";

        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(30); // Set cookie expiration for "Remember Me"
        options.SlidingExpiration = true; // Refresh cookie on activity
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true; // Mitigate XSS risks
                                        //options.Cookie.Secure = true;   // Enforce HTTPS-only cookies (if applicable)
    });
// Add IHttpContextAccessor
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddSession();
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.Run();


Not Working at my side, System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' in Home or Cart Controller

Have you tired different browser? Or could you please share the whole middleware to see if other setting modify it?

now its fine, private readonly long UsId;
public CartController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
{
_httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
 UsId = Convert.ToInt64(_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Sid)?.Value);

}

Do you mean you want to get the sid instead of other user claims ?
